# HTTP GET request with a separate entity body in JMeter?

Tags: jmeter

I want to send a JSON payload with HTTP GET request but I want to prevent it to be viewable in URL.

```
GET http://<domain>/school/search.json

{ 
    schoolId: ["S1","S2","S3"],
    location: "Pune"
}
```

How can I achieve this in JMeter Apache?

Answer (score 0):

Get implies visible in Url, what exactly do you want to do ?

Comment: I want to execute HTTP Get Restful Web Service with Request Body using JMeter. Is there any way to achieve this in JMeter?

Answer (score 0):

Sending Body data along with HTTP GET request is available for [default (HttpClient4) implementation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) since ver.3.1 (as [Bugzilla #60358](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=60358)), as well as request retrying behavior both for PUT and GET with body fixed since ver.3.2 (as [Bugzilla #60837](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=60837)).

Just as additional note: you will likely [encounter problems](https://stackoverflow.com/a/978173/993246) if you have cache/proxies in your setup and if you plan to take advantage from their usage.